# how to generate pdf in vuejs (UPDATED)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf

how to generate pdf using in vuejs , i have given api data below.
    columns Date, Temperature, Humidity. and i am not getting data out from axios call.

```
      [
        {
          "Humidity": "70.50", 
          "Temperature": "25.50", 
          "time": "2019-08-28T10:04:22.597533952Z"
        }, 
        {
          "Humidity": "70.50", 
          "Temperature": "25.40", 
          "time": "2019-08-28T10:09:23.709048064Z"
        }, 
        {
          "Humidity": "70.50", 
          "Temperature": "25.40", 
          "time": "2019-08-28T10:14:25.430288128Z"
        }
        ]
```

below is my function

```
   exportpdf(){
         var self = this;
        axios.get("http://34.67.88.0:3000/api/env/fdsfsdf")
        .then(function(res){
          self.datas = res.data[0];

        })

     let columns = [
              {title:"Time",dataKey:"time"},
              {title:"Temperature",dataKey:"Temperature"},
              {title:"Humidity",dataKey:"Humidity"}
              ];
              var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt');
              doc.autoTable(columns,self.datas);
              doc.save("p.pdf");

        },
```

Comment: why are you assigning datas to self ? why dont you use data or variable ?

Comment: self is referd to this keyword

Comment: Does you response has data in it ???

Comment: yeah...i am getting response from that api.. and storing to variable datas...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this piece of code will help you:
This will download pdf that you get from response

```
 const data = Buffer.from(bytes, 'binary');
 const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'pdf' });
 if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
     window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'test.pdf');
    } else {
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.style = 'display: none';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      a.href = url;
      a.download = fileName;
      a.click();

      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        exportpdf(){
            var self = this;
            var report= '';
            axios.get("http://34.67.88.0:8081/api/env/fdsfsdf")
            .then(function(res){
              let columns = [
                  {title:"Time",dataKey:"time"},
                  {title:"Temperature",dataKey:"Temperature"},
                  {title:"Humidity",dataKey:"Humidity"}
                  ];
              var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt');
              doc.autoTable(columns,res.data);
              doc.save("p.pdf");
             }) 
             }
```